# Is there a way to get a Slide Library to show up via relationship to a list?

Tags: 2010, display-form, slidelibrary

I have a list and a slide library with a lookup to the list. On the list item, I want to show related slides.

I edit the list item view and go to Insert>Related Lists and choose "Slides" (the slide library).

I get an error: "This action is only supported on List Templates with supported XSL Views."

How do I show the the slides related to this list item?

I do not have access to Designer :(

Comment: If you don't have access to Designer, how you tried adding Related List? :$

Comment: Yes, and that's when I get the error message above.

Comment: Randy, can you try adding the List Web Part - without this Related Lists option.. and then create a Web Part Connection and send row from your list web part to Slide library web part